# How to get QString::fromAscii in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt5

I have a function to get the name of the computer as QString. While updating my program to Qt5 the function **QString::fromAscii** still doesn't exist anymore. How can I get it to QString?

```
    QString AppConfig::GetMachinename()
    {
        char* buf = new char[512];
        DWORD size;
        int res;
        QString machineName;
        if ((res = GetComputerNameA(buf, &size)))
        {
            machineName = QString::fromAscii(buf, size);
        }
        else
            machineName = "FALSE!";
        return machineName;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring-obsolete.html#fromAscii) for the (obsolete) `fromAscii` function:

> This function does the same as fromLatin1().

So, try this code:

```cpp
//...
if ((res = GetComputerNameA(buf, &size)))
{
    machineName = QString::fromLatin1(buf, size);
}
```

[Further documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromLatin1) for the newer, replacement function.